# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'facebook.json') in Brave Browser

Tags: javascript, brave

I've noticed when I am debugging code (ReactJS in this case) in Brave Browser I see:

```
VM1064:7575 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'facebook.json')
    at getConfig (<anonymous>:7575:42)
    at ClickToLoad.init (<anonymous>:10508:37)
    at ClickToLoad.callInit (<anonymous>:2568:18)
    at <anonymous>:10800:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.init (<anonymous>:10798:26)
getConfig @ VM1064:7575
init @ VM1064:10508
callInit @ VM1064:2568
(anonymous) @ VM1064:10800
init @ VM1064:10798
await in init (async)
apply @ VM1064:10866
(anonymous) @ VM1070:3
(anonymous) @ VM1070:5
inject @ inject.js:110
(anonymous) @ inject.js:204
```

I suspect this is some sort of inject they are doing for ad blocking, but I have no idea what is causing this. It doesn't show in any other browser. Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?